# How to display a list of all categories on the home page

Tags: magento

I want to display a list of all categories on the home page as  links, so when someone clicks then they go that page.

I tried something like this:
I put this code on content of cms -> home page

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/view.phtml"}}


{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But it displays nothing.. my home page becomes blank,
when I put only this:

```
   {{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/view.phtml"}}
```

then all products are displayed correctly..

Comment: this might help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30919/showing-all-categories-down-the-side-of-home-page

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you wish to place these links, there are many ways to achieve this.

### Adding categories to the content

if you wish to place category links in the content of the homepage then this can be achieved easily by heading to **CMS > Pages > Homepage: Design tab** and adding the following to Layout update XML:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Navigation Bar</label>
        <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
        </block>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Then you would have to style it to your liking (to avoid the duplicate menu look).

### Adding categories to the sidebar

If your homepage follows a multi-column layout and you wish to add the links to one of the sidebars then this is a little more tricky.

The best way would be to [create your own module here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643). After head to app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout/ and add the following to your xml layout:

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
            <label>Navigation Bar</label>
            <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
            </block>
       </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Depending on what layout your homepage conforms to you would replace the **default** tag with **page_two_columns_left, page_two_columns_right, page_three_columns** etc. Again you'll have to style it to your liking.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code in the `wysiwyg editor` to achieve the above

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/product/mycatt.phtml"}}
```

It seems to work well.